# error on jsp using formatDate

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to format a date to this pattern 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' and I am getting the error

> com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPErrorReport: /reclam/alter.jsp(257,30) JSPG0055E: Unable to create an xml attribute from name [] value [&gt;
>                               &lt;fmt:formatDate value=]
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocumentAsJspPage(Jsp2Dom.java:300)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.document.Jsp2Dom.getJspDocument(Jsp2Dom.java:179)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslator.(JspTranslator.java:73)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslatorFactory.createTranslator(JspTranslatorFactory.java:116)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJsp(JspTranslatorUtil.java:181)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJspAndCompile(JspTranslatorUtil.java:84)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:386)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:354)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:263)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:137)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
>       at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1439)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)

Here is my piece of code:

```
    <bean:size collection="${beanAlter.CAllAlterLotes}" id="histSize"/>
                        <layout:pager maxPageItems="20">
                        <layout:collection name="beanAlter" styleClass="layout" indexId="id" id="event" property="CAllAlterLotes" onRowMouseOut="this.style.background='#FFF'" onRowMouseOver="this.style.background='#66C2CD'; this.style.cursor='default';">  
                            <layout:collectionItem title="reclam.alter.dataInicio"">
 <fmt:formatDate value="${event.dataInicio}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"  />
</layout:collectionItem>
```

Comment: You have a double double quote here: `title="reclam.alter.dataInicio""`.

Comment: @JBNizet omg... 2 hours wasted looking for this. it works!